# Showing that $\{0\}$ is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

My professor today asked us to show that $\{0\}$ is a vector space, and while I feel like it 'obviously' satisfies the vector space conditions, I missed the explanation, and I'm worried I may be wrong. Also, another student suggested that it is just the definition of a vector space. Can somebody just give a solid proof?

Comment: Your textbooks probably lists all of the properties of a vector space. Just clearly check that {0} satisfies each property and you should be convinced.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $\{0\}$ is a vector space, we need only check that it satisfies the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

For example, to check vector addition is associative on this set, we need only check that $0+(0+0)=(0+0)=0$.  It is, both sides equal $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the list of the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), and show that each holds when you put in $\vec 0$ as your vector.